# Adding fields that can contain null together in lambda/linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have a dropdownlist which I want to fill with five fields from the database.
I am using `Entity framework 6` and `lambda/linq`.
I have two problems.

1. When I add the fields together it only shows the first field (a.tblRegion.Name) in the dropdownlist. I want it to look like "region" "store" "location" "date". How ever Except for the "region" field they can all be null.
2. I also want one of the fields to be a date field but it throws an error.

My code at the moment looks like this.

```
var query = db.tblActivityReports.Where(ap => ap.Deleted == false)
  .Select(a => new
  {
    activity = a.tblRegion.Name != "" ? a.tblRegion.Name : string.Empty + " " + 
    a.tblStore.Name != "" ? a.tblStore.Name : string.Empty + " " + 
    a.Location != "" ? a.Location : string.Empty, 
    activityId = a.ActivityReportId, 
    participant = a.tblActivityParticipants
   });
```

If I add the date field I get this error: 
`"Unable to cast the type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."`

Comment: Which one of these fields is first? Which one is date?

Comment: Aah, sorry. I have been changing it back and forth. The date field fell out.

Comment: Hmm, comment section isn't my friend. :) What do you mean with first?

Comment: Just update your question. By first I mean which field makes your first problem?

Comment: The region.Name field is the one that shows up in the dropdownlist. The other fields are just skipped.

Comment: tblRegion and tblStore is required dependencies? I.e. can activity report have any of them equal null? Also what is expected activity string?

Comment: The tblRegion is required but the store (and the other fields) can be null. The string could look like: "region" "store" "location" "date" or "region" "store" "date" or "region" "date" or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to get required data from database, and then do formatting of data on client side - actually formatting strings for UI on database is not very good idea. So, after loading all required data you will be able to use String.Format and convert DateTime to string:

```
db.tblActivityReports
  .Where(ar => !ar.Deleted)
  .Select(ar => new {
     RegionName = ar.tblRegion.Name,
     StoreName = (ar.tblStore == null ? null : ar.tblStore.Name),
     ar.Location,
     ar.ActivityDate,
     ActivityId = ar.ActivityReportId, 
     Participants = ar.tblActivityParticipants 
  })
  .AsEnumerable() // move query to memory
  .Select(x => new {
     Activity = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}",
                   x.RegionName, x.StoreName, x.Location, x.ActivityDate),
     x.ActivityId,
     x.Participants
  });
```

You even can map results to some ViewModel which will be responsible to return formatted string.

HINT: If you want values concatenated with white space, then you can use String.Join instead of formatting:

```
Activity = String.Join(" ", 
 (new object[] { x.RegionName, x.StoreName, x.Location, x.ActivityDate })
 .Where(o => o != null))
```

Comment: I don't know if it is a vb.net thing but in C# at least this ar.tblStore = null ? null... Should be ar.tblStore == null ? null.

Comment: Ok. I just want to thank you once again. That really made my day. Now I can relax for the rest of the weekend.